# Selection Formula with Date Pickers

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a form(TrimQuery) that has 2 editable date picker fields (Start_Date & End_Date) and a button. On the push of a button I need to pull up a pre-existing view(All Trim Tracking) from another Form(Trim Track) that polls a field(Trim_Date) and displays all documents between the dates I specified in the (TrimQuery) form using the date pickers. I have posted the code below.

Is there another way to view documents between two dates? I think most of my problem lies in the selection formula, which I have posted with the code, but I know it's incorrect. I've tried to grab bits of code from other examples. Please pick this apart. I appreciate any help I can get . Thanks.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)

Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim workspace As NotesUIWorkspace
Dim doc As NotesDocument
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim StartDate As NotesItem
Dim EndDate As NotesItem
Dim Trimming As String

Trimming = "Trim Track"

Set StartDate = doc.GetFirstItem("Start_Date")
Set EndDate = doc.GetFirstItem("End_Date")
Set uidoc=workspace.CurrentDocument
Set db=session.CurrentDatabase
Set view=db.GetView("All Trim Tracking")

SF = {SELECT Trim_Date = "} & StartDate.Text & "&" & EndDate.Text & {" | (Form = }& Trimming & {")} <==I realize this is incorrect, I don't know the correct formula.

If StartDate.Text <> "" And EndDate.Text <> "" Then
view.SelectionFormula = SF
Else
view.SelectionFormula="select @all"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express date ranges in selection formulas:

```
SF = {SELECT Trim_Date = [} & StartDate.Text & "-" & EndDate.Text & {] & Form = "} & Trimming & {"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do searches outside a view (for a view isn't supposed to be modified on the fly), you'd better use full-text searching: NotesDatabase.FTSearch  The syntax is a little more complex, and not fully compatible with the Selection formula possibilities. If the database isn't large, you can also use the NotesDatabase.Search method: same syntax as for a view, but a sequential (=slow) search.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to get a sub-group of documents from a view, you'd best use a [Full-text search on the view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FTSEARCH_METHOD_VIEW.html) you're interested in. Syntax for full-text searching can be found [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/full-text-syntax). I would recommend this over a database FT search because you're only interested in documents that are in a specific view, not necessarily all documents in the database.

You haven't been specific about how you want to view the documents once the search is complete. The only logical UI structure to use for search results would be a Folder, otherwise you're faced with a long and complicated process to create a custom UI that manages the data. You can embed a view into the search form itself, (you can link folders as well), or present the folder in a [dialogbox](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DIALOGBOX_METHOD.html).

When dealing with folders, you need to remember to remove the contents of the folder, and then populate it. The only drawback is that if you're using a public folder, you can't have multiple users doing it at the same time. Alternatively, you can make the folders private on first use. Check out NotesDocumentCollection.PutAllInFolder and NotesDocumentCollection.RemoveAllFromFolder to help you manage folder contents.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use LotusScript to alter a views selection formula, primarily because anyone using such code would be altering the design of the view and even if done via an agent signed by the server ID you might well run into problems if multiple users were accessing the date picker code simultaneously.

I would create sorted via with the minimum number of sorted columns needed and scan for start of matching documents and end using notesViewEntry methods. I use that quite often and its very fast, even on large numbers of documents and its easy to turn it into a list for your user to choose from.

I steer away from full text searches as a first approach because by their nature the baseline is all documents of all types in the database hence it won't be efficient if your database is large or contains many different types of documents.